# Google App Script: Why is my app blocked when trying to run it with my personal Google Account?

Tags: google-apps-script

When I started learning GAS development, I used my personal Google Account, and I'd never encountered any problem. Later I started use my organization's account to do GAS developing and everything works fine. Recently when I try to make some GAS projects of my own using my personal account, I got this error:
[image]

even though what I'm trying to run is just console.log(1).

I've tried my other personal account, they don't have this problem. So this must be related with some settings of my personal account or maybe I need to clear something restriction with Google. Can anyone tell me where I should find these thigns?